# Passing a variable from sqlplus to unix and then to php

Tags: php, shell, unix, sqlplus

I have a php script that calls a shell script.
The shell script runs sql commands and the output is transferred to a shell variable.
Now, how do I pass this variable to the PHP script?

Eg: PHP Code:

```
$_param1 = "JOHNDOE";
$out = exec("sh shellscript.ksh $_param1");
echo $out;
```

Shell Script:

```
#!/bin/sh -u

param=$1;

out=`sqlplus -s $connectStr <<EOF

set serveroutput off;
set feedback off;
set heading off;
set pagesize 0;
set verify off;
set echo off;

select field from sometable where condition ='$param';
exit;
EOF`

echo $out;
```

I need to transfer the $out to the PHP page. Is there a way other than creating a file?

Answer (score 0):

Pass $out as parameter of 'exec', so that the return of the shell will be stored on that var.

**myshell.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

**myphp.php**

```
<?php
$param = "HEY, this is Output";
exec("sh myshell.sh \"${param}\"", $out);
print_r($out);
?>
```

Then call the PHP script

```
$ php myphp.php 
Array
(
    [0] => HEY, this is Output
)
```

Maybe you might be having some permission issue on executing the Shell or even your PHP configuration might be wrong.

Comment: I've tried that too. I've tried it with the system() function also. But nothing ever seems to be populating the output into the php variable. When I run the shell script seperately on a Unix prompt, the required output is produced on the shell. Any ideas?

Comment: Check out my update, I think that you might be having permission issues, try to call that script with the user of your Web Server to see the results.

Comment: I have a hunch that the issue here is that PHP is not picking up the echo'ed data, ie just the value. It just shows a blank array - Array ( ). For eg: When I echo "Hello World", it picks up the data and outputs it. But for this value, it is acting kinda strange.